# Data for the result set when expanded gets overridden for the previous expanded set in angular project

Tags: angular, datagridview, datagrid, expand, angular12

There are expand icons for each data row. When expand is clicked then the api is hit and result set is being fetched.
The problem is that when the expand for other row is clicked, then the data are overridden for the previous expanded result set.

```
<clr-datagrid>
    <clr-dg-column>Order ID
        <clr-dg-string-filter [clrDgStringFilter]="orderFilter"></clr-dg-string-filter>
    </clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column [clrDgField]="'suborg'" [clrDgSortOrder]="ascSort">Suborg
        <clr-dg-string-filter [clrDgStringFilter]="subOrgFilter"></clr-dg-string-filter>
    </clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column> Rules </clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-column> FailedRules </clr-dg-column>
    <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let order of orders" [clrDgItem]="order" (clrDgExpandedChange)="expandChange($event, order)">
        <clr-dg-cell>{{order.orderID}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{order.suborg}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{order.requestType}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-cell>{{order.failedRules}}</clr-dg-cell>
        <clr-dg-row-detail *clrIfExpanded [clrDgReplace]="order.replace">
            <ng-template ngProjectAs="clr-dg-row-detail" [(clrIfExpanded)]="order.expanded">
                <clr-dg-row-detail>
                    <div class="dg-wrapper">
                        <clr-datagrid>
                            <clr-dg-column [style.width.px]="250">Message Type</clr-dg-column>
                            <clr-dg-column [style.width.px]="200">Process Time</clr-dg-column>
                            <clr-dg-column [style.width.px]="50">Status </clr-dg-column>
                            <clr-dg-column [style.width.px]="50"> Message </clr-dg-column>
                            <clr-dg-row *clrDgItems="let data of ordersinfo" [clrDgItem]="data">
                                <clr-dg-cell>{{data.type}}</clr-dg-cell>
                                <clr-dg-cell>{{data.timeStamp}}</clr-dg-cell>
                                <clr-dg-cell> <span class="color-square" [style.backgroundColor]="data.color"></span> </clr-dg-cell>
                                <clr-dg-cell> <a [routerLink]="" (click)="open(data)">show</a></clr-dg-cell>
                            </clr-dg-row>
                        </clr-datagrid>
                    </div>
                </clr-dg-row-detail>
            </ng-template>
        </clr-dg-row-detail>
    </clr-dg-row>
</clr-datagrid>
```

And the function to expand is like below:

```
expandChange(value, row) {
    this.selectedrow = row;
    if (value) {
      console.log("In selected Changed", row);
      this.spinnerService.show();
      this._order.getOrderData(row.orderID, row.status, row.suborg).subscribe(res => {
        this.searchordersinfo = res;
        this.searchordersinfo = this.searchordersinfo.filter(x => x != null);
      });
    }
 }
```

The data are displayed as
[image]

Now when I click the expand icon for first record, it shows as:
[image]

After that when I click the expand icon for second record, the result set for first one get overridden by the second set.
[image]

One more problem is there that alignment also gets changed.

Comment: Can you also add the Typescript code of the component and the SpinnerService?

Comment: @LeBavarois, You can ignore the SpinnerService. This is just for loader.